# How to remove nested for loops and use numpy arrays insead

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv, for-loop, numpy-indexing

I have a video comprising of 580 frames. I need to be able to detect the green color from the video and create a mask so as to put zero values where green is found and the rest should be 255. I have converted the video in HSV format and am using nested for loops and it takes about an hour to do this I was wondering if there was a faster way of doing this.
Here is my current code

```
for i in range(0, len(temp)):
   temp[i] = cv2.cvtColor(temp[i], cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
for k in range(0, len(temp)):
    for i in range(0, len(temp[k])):
        for j in range(0, len(temp[k][i])):
           if(temp[k][i][j][0] > 50 and temp[k][i][j][0] < 65 and temp[k][i][j][2] > 150):
               temp1[k][i][j][0] = 0
               temp1[k][i][j][1] = 0
               temp1[k][i][j][2] = 0
           else:
               temp1[k][i][j][0] = 255
               temp1[k][i][j][1] = 255
               temp1[k][i][j][2] = 255
```

temp is my HSV array and temp1 is the mask i am creating

Comment: Look into color thresholding using `cv2.inRange()`

Comment: I was looking for an answer without the in range function thank you though for suggesting it

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't want to use `cv2.inRange()`?? It is probably the best method since it's vectorized, has adjustable minimum/maximum color thresholds, and will give you a output mask with the desired green pixels in white and the background in black

Comment: It's part of a silly assignment that's why. That's why I marked the question complete. Because even though I am still looking to optimize those loops but the problem of not using cv2.inRange isn't a very realistic one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a `cv2` expert, but if it works like `numpy` arrays, then . . .

```
for i in range(0, len(temp)):
   temp[i] = cv2.cvtColor(temp[i], cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
   temp1[i] = (1 - cv2.inRange(temp[i], (50, 0, 150), (65, 255, 255)).astype(int)) * 255
```